# Need Regex to match url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of urls starting with:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/https://www.example.com
http://www.exampleTwo.com
```

I want to use regex to get all the urls starting from

```
http://www.example.com
```

This is what I have so far

```
var url = (' http://www.example.com');
var expression = /^http?:\/\/example\.com/\;
if (url != expression) { 
alert ("success");
}
```

Any one can shed a light on this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: Does it always start with `http://www` ?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm not actually answering your question, but I don't think it makes any sense to use regex here, when you can just use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), specifically:

```
if(url.indexOf('http://www.example.com') == 0){
    alert('success');
}
```

If you *need* to use regex, feel free to disregard,

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

```
var url = ('http://www.example.com');
var expression = new RegExp("^http:\/\/www\.example\.com.*");
if (expression.test(url)) { 
alert ("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = 'http://www.example.com';
str.match(/^http\:\/\/www\.example\.com.*$/);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/4)